# Subversion for Winforms

Tags: winforms, svn

Can anyone one tell me if subversion works fine with Winforms?
I've used it in webforms with asp.net and i love it, but i'm confused of wheter is good with winforms or not.
Does it manage ok conflicts? what about merges ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference.
Subversion has no idea what technology you are using and will happily merge anything plain-text.

Because code is plain-text, and WinForms programming is mostly code (resources are XML, no problem here as well), Subversion will work fine for you.

Comment: that's all i needed to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Subversion doesn't know the difference between webforms & winforms, they are all code files as far as SVN is concerned.